# Wavefront OBJ import to OpenGL ES 2.0 problems

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I finally finished building my Wavefront OBJ parser, but still have some issues rendering my test object (cube).

So this is how i have parsed my vertices and indices (faces) into arrays of data. I have ignored textures and normals for now.

Vertices:

```
v -0.307796 0.00433517 0
v 0.299126 0.00433517 0
v 0.299126 0.00433517 0.48337
v -0.307796 0.00433517 0.48337
v -0.307796 0.364153 0.48337
v 0.299126 0.364153 0.48337
v 0.299126 0.364153 0
v -0.307796 0.364153 0
```

As:

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {-0.307796,0.00433517,0},
    {0.299126,0.00433517,0},
    {0.299126,0.00433517,0.48337},
    {-0.307796,0.00433517,0.48337},
    {-0.307796,0.364153,0.48337},
    {0.299126,0.364153,0.48337},
    {0.299126,0.364153,0},
    {-0.307796,0.364153,0}
};
```

Faces:

```
f 7/1/1 3/2/2 2/3/3
f 3/4/4 7/5/5 6/6/6
f 5/7/7 1/8/8 4/9/9
f 1/10/10 5/11/11 8/12/12
f 7/13/13 1/14/14 8/15/15
f 1/16/16 7/17/17 2/18/18
f 3/19/19 5/20/20 4/21/21
f 5/22/22 3/23/23 6/24/24
f 5/25/25 7/26/26 8/27/27
f 7/28/28 5/29/29 6/30/30
f 3/31/31 1/32/32 2/33/33
f 1/34/34 3/35/35 4/36/36
```

As:

```
const GLubyte Indices[] = {
7,1,1, 3,2,2, 2,3,3,
3,4,4, 7,5,5, 6,6,6,
5,7,7, 1,8,8, 4,9,9,
1,10,10, 5,11,11, 8,12,12,
7,13,13, 1,14,14, 8,15,15,
1,16,16, 7,17,17, 2,18,18,
3,19,19, 5,20,20, 4,21,21,
5,22,22, 3,23,23, 6,24,24,
5,25,25, 7,26,26, 8,27,27,
7,28,28, 5,29,29, 6,30,30,
3,31,31, 1,32,32, 2,33,33,
1,34,34, 3,35,35, 4,36,36
};
```

Indices only as vertex positions:

```
const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    7, 3, 2, 
    3, 7, 6, 
    5, 1, 4, 
    1, 5, 8, 
    7, 1, 8, 
    1, 7, 2, 
    3, 5, 4, 
    5, 3, 6, 
    5, 7, 8, 
    7, 5, 6, 
    3, 1, 2, 
    1, 3, 4 
};
```

SetupVBO:

```
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint indexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Renderingcode:

```
glClearColor(0, 104.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
[projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:10];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
[modelView populateFromTranslation:CC3VectorMake(sin(CACurrentMediaTime()), 0, -7)];
_currentRotation += displayLink.duration * 90;
[modelView rotateBy:CC3VectorMake(_currentRotation, _currentRotation, 0)];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

// 1
glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

// 2
glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

// 3
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

And the result is pretty much nothing at all, so there must be something that im doing completely wrong.

Furthermore will the indices cause any problems since i have not initialized the normals or texture coords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wavefront obj format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) says that if you have sequences of 3 in the face definitions then their meaning is:

```
vertex-index/vertex-texture-index/vector-normal-index
```

You are reading all of the indices into a single array `GLubyte Indices[]` and using it as it if was just the indices of the vertices.
If you want to do away with textures and normals, you need to take only the first number of every triplet.
In

```
f 6/1/1 3/2/2 2/3/3 7/4/4
```

The face is a quad of vertices of indices [6,3,2,7]. Using the indices array like you have requires that you tell OpenGl that the indices are multiplexed in triplets. It does not look like you do that. It also requires additional buffers for normal and texture coordinates.

Comment: Im sorry, that is a huge typo! I forgot to triangulate my object. Which i have done now. Will update/edit my primary post.

Comment: The post has been modified with the triangulated object now.
So if i just take the first value (position) of the face, im good to go? Do i have to modify glDrawElements?

Comment: I have changed my parser to output only the positions in the faces. I get something now, but its not entirely a cube. Looks like a cube missing some connections. So i assume my indices is being read all wrong?